# What happens if limit of Sql Server Compact Edition is reached?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

What happens if a database reaches the limit of 4GB of the SQL Server Compact Edition? Is there a special exception for this?

Can I safely catch this event or exception and, let's say, create a new database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not experienced this myself, but it looks like a [`SqlCeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceexception.aspx) will be thrown and the `NativeError` property of the contained [SqlCeError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceerror.aspx) will have an error code of 25104 (SSCE_M_DATABASETOOBIG).

Here's a [listing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171879.aspx) of `SqlCeError` Native Codes related to db engine errors -- the one about the db file being too big is about 2/3 of the way down.  The listing is for SQL CE 3.5; you didn't specify what version you were using, but I'm guessing that it wouldn't change.

I don't see why you couldn't catch this exception and then create a new database in your `catch` section.

```
try {
  //do something
} catch (SqlCeException cexc){
  foeach (SqlCeError aError in cexc.Errors) {
    if (aError.NativeError == 25104) {  //this is the code for the TOO BIG error code
      //handle too big error -- maybe create a new database
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!